# Suggestion for rewriting query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table(TABLEA) with 1 million of records and records are populated from multiple sources into this table(TABLEA).
once data is populated the records processed by downstream.

Whenever data is inserted the value of the column FLAG will be null and once its processed by down stream
the value of the FLAG will be updated as Y.

So basically I have requirement to check before records getting processed by downstream.

Requirement is that for already processed records in TABLEA(FLAG='Y') and CODE='I',  I need to check
is there any other records with same value for COLB  where the FLAG is null. If its there I want to change the CODE='D'(which means marked for delete) and FLAG=NULL

I write a merge for this and its taking like 3 hours to
run. I tried with explain plan and it didnt show me any recommendation. So is there anwyay to rewrite this query.

```
MERGE INTO TABLEA SRC
using
(select COLB from TABLEA where FLAG IS NULL) TGT
on(SRC.COLB=TGT.COLB and SRC.FLAG is not null and SRC.CODE='I')
when matched then update set 
CODE='D',FLAG = NULL;
commit;
```

This is my input record and before executing the merge query query

```
COLA     COLB  CODE FLAG
 -------------- --------- ---- ----
 10001   3060   I    Y
 10002   3548   I    Y
 10003   3566   I    Y
 10004   5093   I    Y
 10005   3548   I    Y
 10008   3060   I    NULL
```

My output should look like something below. Here the COLB value is same for first record(already processed) and last record(yet to process), so after the merge query
this is how the TABLEA looks like

```
COLA     COLB  CODE FLAG
 -------------- --------- ---- ----
 10001   3060   D    NULL
 10002   3548   I    Y
 10003   3566   I    Y
 10004   5093   I    Y
 10005   3548   I    Y
 10008   3060   I    NULL
```

Comment: I think you could speed up by using another isolation level (WITH RS/CS/UR), if not already set...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `UPDATE` statement:

```
update tablea a
set code = 'D', flag = null
where flag = 'Y' and code = 'I'
  and exists (
    select 1 from tablea b where b.colb = a.colb and b.flag is null
  );
```

In order to [substantially] improve the performance you can create the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on tablea (flag, code);

create index ix2 on tablea (colb, flag);
```

Comment: thank you, I will test this and see the performance

Answer (score 0):

You could have a speed up when the indexes contains all the 3 fields, so db2 can make index scans for the search and needs to read/write on the tablespace only when an update is needed.